# Using a generic type argument with `typeof T`

Tags: typescript

I have a factory-like function that is meant to return an sub-class instance of `BaseApi`. It currently looks something like this (trimmed out irrelevant parts):

```
function getApi<T extends BaseApi>(apiClass: typeof BaseApi): T {
    return new apiClass();
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
const someApi = getApi<SomeApi>(SomeApi);
```

This works, but I would like `<SomeApi>` to be inferred by virtue of the fact that I'm passing the `SomeApi` constructor in. If I omit `<SomeApi>` then `someApi` is inferred to be of type `BaseApi`, not `SomeApi`. Worse, there's really no compiler correlation between `<T extends BaseApi>` and `typeof BaseApi` being the same thing, so you can incorrectly do something like `getApi<SecondApi>(FirstApi)` without a compiler error.

So I tried defining the `apiClass` as `typeof T`:

```
function getApi<T extends BaseApi>(apiClass: typeof T): T {
    return new apiClass();
}
```

And I found that TS did not understand this usage of `T`. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

What you actually want is `new() => T`, since you intend to use the argument as a constructor and produce a `T`. Even if you could write `typeof T`, that wouldn't be what you want, since `T` might not have a zero-argument constructor.

Remember that the `typeof` operator takes a **value** and produces a **value**. `T` is already a type; it is not a value.

Naturally, this is addressed in the TypeScript FAQ https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-cant-i-write-typeof-t-new-t-or-instanceof-t-in-my-generic-function

Comment: Nailed it, thanks Ryan! (You literally answered so fast that SO won't let me accept it yet.)

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics

Comment: in a case where you use parameterless constructor and constrcutors that take parameters you need to update `new() => T` to `new (...args)=>T` otherwise you will get a compile error.

Comment: Maybe this should be a separate question, but what if my `T` extends a base class (because I used `<T extends BaseClass>`), and `BaseClass` has a public static method like `myStaticMethod()` which I want to call? Is it possible to make typescript aware of the fact that not only I want my variable to be a (0-arg) constructor (`new() => T`), but also I want to be able to call `myStaticMethod()` on it?

Comment: @NicolasB Why not `arg: { new(): T; myStaticMethod(): any; }` in that case?

Comment: @Arad I think that what you write is perfectly correct, and it answers my question. However it doesn't scale really well if there are many static methods in the base class, with verbose types. I thought about it some more and I think that an option that works is: `arg: (new() => T) & typeof BaseClass;`. The first part of the intersection type takes care of the constructor part, the second part takes care of the static methods.