# How to use a function input type of "typeof A" to return type "A"?

Tags: typescript

I have this sandbox example

```
class A {
    doSomething() {}
}
class B {}

const collection = {
    a: new A(),
    b: new B()
}

const findInstance = <T>(list: any, nonInstance: T): T => {
    for (const item in list) {
    if (list[item] instanceof (nonInstance as any)) {
            return list[item] as any
        }
    }
    throw new Error('Unable to find thingo')
}

const a: A = findInstance(collection, A)

a.doSomething()
```

The type error I get is

```
Property 'doSomething' is missing in type 'typeof A' but required in type 'A'.
```

What I am getting is `typeof A` what I want is `A`

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQCYHsDKmC2ApgC4AWAlgHYDmAFAJSIC+SzokMAQk0ksJhRCLQ+IEAWBEy-aAF5EKNGABc0CgQDucegBoFqAEYq1mjvRY8+AoQDNK6AJJWwFYAVnQAPABUAfDRBkgirOAJ7aqvyOgs6uKl50cbI+8mjQ1pgATtA0loLQZEQEePkU0AGCDMipZNbZ5UQA2gVFALol0S4EmLU0FJFOndCQQxQhdJV6qVMZxACuGaX1TYV4bcOhk6nMW5OkGZiaxtAAohn7GTQA5ACqFGD6YtBEmGl2T+TUmJd05rz8eco4O5bBQHANXDlMKJxJJ+OFYD8kGAAHRYXCEUiUWh0IA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `nonInstance` type declaration from `T` to `new(...args: any[]) => T`.

Here's the updated function signature:

```
const findInstance = <T>(list: any, nonInstance: new(...args: any[]) => T): T => {
    // ...
}
```

This indicates that you want the constructor for type T, rather than an instance of type T itself.

Here's a related question: [Using a generic type argument with `typeof T`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249906/using-a-generic-type-argument-with-typeof-t)

And another example the TypeScript Handbook: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use 'new' with this expression? I think not because you called your variable nonInstance...  Type of A is the class itself which lack of the doSomething method (unless you would use the `static` Keyword but it is not the proper solution either)... Therefore I think you will need to include new() => T to tell the compiler that you want to compare with an instance,

```
const findInstance = <T>(list: any, instance: new () => T): T => {
  for (const item in list) {
    if (list[item] instanceof (instance as any)) {
      return list[item] as any;
    }
  }
  throw new Error('Unable to find thingo');
};
```